# c++ modules clang compilation fails

Tags: c++

following various guides, Here's a working clang compilation example:

**main.cpp**

```
import mymodule;

int main()
{
    f(5);
    g(0.0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

**mymodule.ixx**

```
export module mymodule;

export int f(int x)
{
    return 2 + x;
}
export double g(double y, int z)
{
    return y * z;
}
```

Here's how I compile (ubuntu):

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module mymodule.ixx -o mymodule.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts -c mymodule.pcm -o mymodule.o
clang++ -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. mymodule.o main.cpp -o compiled
```

However, changing the main file to include std.core, generates an error:

**modified main.cpp**

```
import mymodule;
import std.core;

int main()
{
    f(5);
    g(0.0, 1);
    std::cout << "Done\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**error**

```
main.cpp:2:8: fatal error: module 'std.core' not found
```

Why can't I use std.core properly?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I would guess you need to use `libc++`instead of `libstdc++`.

Comment: Where and how? simply adding a flag didn't do the trick

Comment: So adding `-stdlib=libc++` did not work?

Comment: Nope, didn't work